# Outlook 2013 overwrittes copied Autocomplete address

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Recently I reinstalled Windows 10 and backed up all the email. Additionally I copied the autocomplete list from

> \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache\Stream_Autocomplete...

Then I restore the outlook data from .pst and sent a test mail
so a new autocomplete list was created.

After that I coped the old autocomplete
file and renamed it, so it matched the new file name.

After restarting outlook the file was overwritten and contained only the address that I send the test mail to.

I tried to copy over the data from the old file to the new file, but the result is the same. No matter what I do the autocomplete will contain only the entry created on this computer.

I followed the instructions from here [Outlook 2013 | 2010 - Export Auto Fill / Auto Complete data](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=38759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use free [Convert Auto-Complete Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAutoCompleteFilesConvert) and [Import Auto-Complete List](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAutoCompleteImport) utilities for that:

1. Convert your Stream_*.dat files to XML by using the first utility setting the "Convert files to XML format" option.
2. Import the resulting XML files into your Outlook by using the second tool.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend these utilities because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: Great program. It works werry well. You should put a biger or other colored dowload button on the website, so it would pop out more. But the program is amazing.